# Closing the "another edit was made" left whitespace over the top bar

Tags: bug, edits, top-bar

If you look up right now at the top bar, you shouldn't see any whitespace at the top of the page (above the top bar).

But that's not what happened when I was doing first posts. I was editing, saw a message that an edit was made, submitted my edit, closed the orange alert banner and was left with this:

[image]

I was forced to reload the page, because hitting I'm done does not clear it.

It happens every time I close that banner, not just first posts.

Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on Mac (10.7.5), BTW.

Minor bug, not a big priority, but I just thought you should know.

Comment: Looks like a cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133441/banner-dismissal-after-concurrent-edits.

Comment: What browser? What OS? And what versions of both?

Comment: @Oded Chrome & Mac, see my edits.